# Getting Cannot read property 'then' of undefined when using .fromFnPromise in angular-datatables

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

```
//the controller that creates the datatable
app.controller('AdminListCtrl', function ($scope, $compile, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder, adminService) {

    var vm = this;

    function stateChange(iColumn, bVisible) {
      console.log('The column', iColumn, ' has changed its status to', bVisible);
    }

    //vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromSource('http://localhost/api-v1/admin')
    vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromFnPromise(function() {
                return adminService.loadAdmin();
            })
      .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
      .withOption('createdRow', createdRow)
      // Add Bootstrap compatibility
      .withBootstrap()
      // Active ColVis plugin
      .withColVis()
      // Add a state change function
      .withColVisStateChange(stateChange)
      // Exclude the last column from the list
      .withColVisOption('aiExclude', [2])
      // Add Table tools compatibility
      .withTableTools('scripts/vendor/datatables/TableTools/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf')
      .withTableToolsButtons([
        'copy',
        'print', {
          'sExtends': 'collection',
          'sButtonText': 'Save',
          'aButtons': ['csv', 'xls', 'pdf']
        }
      ]);

//adminService to request for all administrators
app.factory('adminService', ['ApiService', function (ApiService) {
    return {
        loadAdmin: function () {   
            ApiService.get("admin").then(function (response) {
                if (response) {
                    if (response.success === true) {
                        return response;
                    }else{
                        console.log(response);
                    }
                }else {
                    console.log('error request ');
                }
            });
        }
    };
}]);
//apiservice to interact with api
app.factory('ApiService', function ($http, $q, $localStorage) {
    return {
        get: function (apiresource) {
            var returnData = $q.defer();
            $http({
                url: api + apiresource,
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {"Auth-Token": $localStorage.user_data.auth_token}
            })
                .success(function (data) {
                    returnData.resolve(data);
                })
                .error(function (error) {
                    returnData.resolve();
                });
            return returnData.promise;
        }};
});`enter code here`
```

When ever I am in that view it throws this errorCannot read property 'then' of undefined. I am following examples from these two sources
http://www.revillweb.com/angularjs-by-example/4-sharing-data-with-angularjs-services/
http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/withPromise

Answer (score 2):

You need to return promise object (result of `ApiService.get("admin")` call) from `loadAdmin` method.

Also make sure you don't "swallow" rejections inside of the `then` (in `console.log` branches) - what happens when you unintentionally handle errors by not passing it further. For this return rejected promise or simply throw error, so that rejection will propagate further down the promise chain:

```
app.factory('adminService', ['ApiService', function (ApiService) {
    return {
        loadAdmin: function () {   
            return ApiService.get("admin").then(function (response) {
                if (response) {
                    if (response.success === true) {
                        return response;
                    } else{
                        console.log(response);
                        throw response; 
                        // or custom error object: throw {message: 'Error loadAdmin', response}
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log('error request ');
                    throw new Error('error request');
                }
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```